# How to execute a javascript/jquery function only after the completion of another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, asynchronous, callback

I know this is a simple question, but I don't really know how to do it. I'm executing two functions in my code, 'luxboxEngine' and 'fitToScreen', the latter of which requires the completion of the former. How do I tell 'fitToScreen' to only execute after 'luxboxEngine' has completed? Right now I have this, which gets the desired results:

```
luxboxEngine(self);
setTimeout(fitToScreen, 1000);
```

...But I know that's not a good solution. I've read about callback functions, but I'm afraid I don't really get what they are / how to incorporate them. Thanks for reading.

EDIT: So as Sudharsan Sri and Brian McGinity answered below, a callback is the solution. Here's the code I used to get what I need in my program:

```
    luxboxEngine(self, function () {
       fitToScreen(); 
    });
```

That fires the fitToScreen function after the completion of luxboxEngine.

Comment: What is "luxboxEngine" and how does it work? Is it synchronous? Asynchronous? If it's asynchronous and doesn't provide a callback or Promise mechanism (it *should*, see the documentation), then you're up a creek without a paddle and have to fall back to flailing wildly (e.g. setTimeout or other hack) in the canoe.

Comment: Self means 'this' in Javascript

Comment: luxboxEngine animates a whole bunch of stuff, and self is a variable passed as a parameter containing a picture to be animated.

Comment: @Ber Then it has "complete" events, no?

Comment: I got the answer below, see my edit for explanation. For the purpose of my question, what luxboxEngine and fitToScreen actually do don't matter too much. Cheers!

Comment: @Ber, I just updated my answer... the function being passed as an argument waits to be called... passing it as an argument is like defining a function, it only runs when called.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Brian! Sorry I didn't respond sooner, I've been working on the code, and I think I might need to post a new question to address another issue at play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback:

```
luxboxEngine(self , function() { fitToScreen(); });
```

Comment: Welcome It's my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

like a callback? Pass the function as a argument then call it:

```
 fitToScreen( function(){luxBoxEginie();}  );

 function fitToScreen( cb ) {
  //// do somethings
  cb()
 }
```

or

```
luxboxEngine(self, function (){ fitToScreen(); });

function luxboxEngine( s, cb)} {
 // do somethings
 cb();  //execute the callback function
}
```

fitToScreen() is passed as an argument into luxboxEngine().  fitToScreen() waits to to be executed, and runs only when you do: `cb()`

Comment: Yep a callback is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
luxboxEngine(self); //Executes, returns undefined, nothing happens with return value
fitToScreen(); //The first one is done by the time we get here
```